# How do you compare a position of an object within an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

so i was trying to compare a position of an object within an array with an int variable that i have

I have this variable called stagePos, and i wanna use it to find an object that has the same value for its position in an array

If the stagePos is 1, then i want to find an object that has the position of [1] in an array and do something with it as well as do something with the other object in that array because they don't have the same value as stagePos

```
if(stage[i] != stage[stagePos]){
     Vector3 pos = stage[i].transform.position;
     pos += new Vector3(0f, -4f * Time.deltaTime , 0f);
     stage[i].transform.position = pos;
     stageScript.Invinsible(true);
}
else if(stage[i] == stage[stagePos]){
     Vector3 pos = stage[i].transform.position;
     pos += new Vector3(0f, 4f * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
     stage[i].transform.position = pos;
     stageScript.Invinsible(false);
}
```

Comment: What type of object is `stage` holding?

Comment: if (i ==stagepos) ....

Comment: stage holds a 
public GameObject[] stage;

Comment: If stagePos is an int, what's the issue you are having?

Comment: If stagePos is a Vector3, find its index via `stage.IndexOf(stagePos) `

Comment: I don't know what should i assign the i with to compare it with the stagePos

I have tried to assign i with a for loop i, but when i put it in the update function in unity it would just keep getting iterated every frame, and i don't know how to get around with that

Comment: stagePos is just a regular int, that i manipulate it with an input from the user

Comment: right so if i is your loop variable taken from the code above if you want to see if stagepos is the same as i, if (i == stagepos) ...  OR skip the whole loop and just do stage[StagePos] ....

Comment: Basically i want to check, when i use stagePos its default value is 0, and i get an input from user to increment it to 1, i wanna check whether there's an object in the stage array that has the position of 1, if there is then i wanna do something to it but i also wanna do something to the other object that has a different position 
after it did something, in this case is just moving the object around, i want the code to just sit there and wait until there's a change with the stagePos value, and then do it all over again

Answer (score 0):

> i want the code to just sit there and wait until there's a change with the stagePos value

So basically there is no issue in your code you just want it to be event driven instead of using `Update`. We don't see how and where exactly you change the value of `stagePos` but I would either use a method like

```
public void SetStagePos(int value)
{
    // ignore if same value
    if(stagePos == value) return;

    stagePos = value;

    for(var i = 0; i < stage.Length; i++)
    {
        // This could be actually done in one line
        stage[i].transform.position += new Vector3(0f,(i == stagePos ? 1 : -1) * 4f * Time.deltaTime , 0f);

        //Note: it is unclear where you want to go with the 
        //stageScript.Invisible()
        // since currently you anyway call it for all objects
        // so this will always end up with the value of
        // stageScript.Invisible(i == stage.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

This you would use like e.g.

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.NumPad1))
    {
        SetStagePos(1);
    }
    //etc.
}
```

or alternatively make `stagePos` a property with backing field like

```
private int _stagePos;
private int stagePos
{
    get => _stagePos;
    set =>
    {
        _stagePos = value;
        for(var i = 0; i < stage.Length; i++)
        {
            stage[i].transform.position += new Vector3(0f,(i == stagePos? 1 : -1) * 4f * Time.deltaTime , 0f);

            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Now everytime you assign a new value to `stagePos` the setter is called

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.NumPad1))
    {
        stagePos = 1;
    }
    //etc.
}
```

---

**Note however** that in general your usage of `Time.deltaTime` really makes only sense in the case this is called every frame!

Depends ofcourse also on how you get the user input which you didn't show.